# Foreign key field generates error when add a new record on Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, combobox, foreign-keys

This is my first problem that I'd like to discuss and I would be very grateful if somebody could help.

I use Ms Access and I'm new in working with it.

I have 4 related tables:

1. Person
2. Town
3. Municipality
4. Region.

My main table is Person and it has many fields. One of them is TownID (foreign key/ text /Null possible). The table is related to Town (outer join). Municipality and Region are also related to Town. I have created a query: TownQuery to work easily with these tables and to avoid writing to them. (Working or not with this query my problem is the same.)

I have also form Person to view table Person's records and add new records to it. It has 4 comboboxes:

1. RegionName
2. MunicipalityName
3. TownName
4. TownID.

Their rowsources are filled on cascading way: MunicipalityName filters Municipalities in the selected region etc. TownID rowsource filters only one ID (which I need).

Everything works fine when I edit records, when I create new record with Null value of TownID and when I create new record directly setting TownID.

But when I want to create new record, consequently filling the 4 comboboxes and select the generated in the last one's rowsource TownID an error occurs: "To make changes to this field, first save the record". Saving is also not allowed - other error messages appear etc. Esc key is the only exit from the situation.

I've tried to unite TownName and TownID comboboxes in 1 with 2 columns but it didn't help. Probably there is some conflict with the foreign key but I wonder how it could be solved. That is the way database user should work with the form. It is not necessary TownID to be combobox, but I think it's suitable.

Comment: Why do you have a separate `combobox` for TownName and TownID?  If your Town table has the fields `TownID, TownName` then you town combo should  display TownName while having TownID available as well.

Comment: Yes, my Town table has the both fields, but I need to visualize the both values. TownID is not a custom Autonumber. It is a text field, whose data I get from other tables. It should be available for manipulation, but the user should also be given possibility to work with the combos. However I tried to unite both combos in 1 with 2 columns, but I had the same problem with selecting a value from the rowsource.

Comment: I was wondering the same as @Zaider This is bad design, no way. You should have only one Combo for the same table. And you should only use your TownName combo to adapt the TownID field in your tables. You should not let the user work with the ID, only the name. If you want to see the ID that is selected on TownName combo at all time, add a read-only `textbox` or a `label` beside it and change it's value/caption property using the `afterupdate` event of your TownName combo. As for your error: are all the comboboxes **bounded** to a table field  ??

Comment: TownID is something like Postal (ZIP) code, it's unique, it's known to the public, it's my primary key in Town table, but it's not exactly Postal code. That's why I'd prefer user to be able to use it and I don't think I need another typical Autonumber ID. All of my comboboxes are bound to the "Name" fields of the 3 tables (or I bind them to the fields of TownQuery in some of my attempts. That's the better way, but it doesn't help). I think the problem would be resolved if they are not bound when I create new record, but I don't know how to do this, I could't find OnNew event or sth like that.

Comment: I don't know what exactly happens with the form recordset and the binds when creating new record, how this could be managed. I think a Null value is set on TownID combo by default, it's not a problem to create a record with it, it's not a problem directly to change its value, but when I change some of the combos the problems begin.

Comment: @Thomas G , you said I should have only 1 combo for the same table. My TownQuery consists of fields: TownID, TownName, MunicipalityName and RegionName. I made it on the purpose to work easily with less relations and to protect my data in the 3 tables. Is it really a bad practise to read more data from 1 table/query? What exactly is the conventional way to work with cascading combos? I have engaged many nearby brains to think about the problem, cause I can't continue working on the db, but nobody helped so far. Any whatever ideas? I also replaced Null values with "unapplicable" but-no result.

Comment: I can't make changes on tables: Town, Municipality and Region. I wouldn't like to create separate forms for browsing records and creating new records, because my form has many other controls and all they are working well. By the way, on my form macros work better than vba code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem disappears if comboboxes are not bound.

Comment: It would be wonderful if it was possible the problem to be resolved with bound combos.